# How do I type the &raquo; (») character on the mac keyboard?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, characters

How can I type the `&raquo;` (») character on the mac keyboard? I noticed that I can type a lot of other chacters by using cmd/control/option and keys, but what about this this one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On a UK keyboard <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> gives »

(Found by doing alt and every letter - finding <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> gives «)

Also via System Preferences > Keyboard > Check "Show Keyboard & Character Viewer in menu bar". Then from the menu bar choose "Keyboard Viewer" and this shows all the characters each key gives you, including the various combinations with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and other modifiers.

Comment: Works on a US keyboard, too. [Alt] is the same as [Option].